# Javascript regular expression needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is the format of the css I'm trying to edit using jquery.

```
/*8d*/ .class{color:#444444;}
/*5d*/ .class{background-color:#444444;}
/*3f*/ .class{color:#444444;}
/*9d*/ .class{color:#444444;}
```

I want to replace several entire lines within using Regular Expressions. For example, How do I select line 5d the replace with "/*5d*/ .new{border:#676767;}" so the end result is;

```
/*8d*/ .class{color:#444444;}
/*5d*/ .new{border:#676767;}
/*3f*/ .class{color:#444444;}
/*9d*/ .class{color:#444444;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is regex really the right tool?

Comment: not sure ... just need to do a find and replace on the content of this textbox. can use anything really ... is there any way regex can replace content between two keywords/substrings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace the `5d` line, search for:

```
\/\*(5d)\*\/.*
```

and replace the match with

```
/*\1*/ .new{border:#676767;}
```

Note that `\1` is a backreference to `5d`.

Comment: errr .. how do I replace "5d" with a js variable ? sorry, have tried googling :)

Comment: When you set the regex pattern, you would do it like this: `var regex = new RegExp("\/\*(" + yourVar + ")\*\/.*");` ...assuming `yourVar` contains `5d` or the likes.

Answer (score 1):

could you use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) or [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) / [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
css.replace(/\/\*5d\*\/.*/, '/*5d*/.new{border:#676767;}');
```

Of course if you have your css in that format, with one rule on one line. If you have it on multiple line you'll have to use this:

```
css.replace(/\/\*5d\*\/{.*?}/s, '/*5d*/.new{border:#676767;}');
```

But if you have comments inside you rule things get more complicated and I don't think regex is enough.

Comment: Sadly, REs in most (all?) JS engines don't support look-behind.

Comment: I checked the ECMA-262 v5 and it seems that just lookaheads are specified. Thank you for the information.